# Laravel storage path from config file

Tags: php, laravel, config

I am working on a project in which I see that images are being saved in this way

```
$file_name = $input['image']->store(config('app.files.user_images.folder_name'));
```

Can anyone tell me what's the purpose of config function and it's parameters?

Comment: downvoting for no reason. If you know the answer then answer here rather than downvoting.

Comment: You're likely being downvoted because that information could've been easily found in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#accessing-configuration-values) and it looks like you made no attempt to find it on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file system configuration file is located at `config/filesystems.php`. Within this file, you may configure all of your `"disks"`. Each disk represents a particular storage driver and storage location.

```
config('app.files.user_images.folder_name')
```

`Note:` it returns folder or file path.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem

Comment: I just want to say that the `filesystems.php` config file and the `app.files.user_images.folder_name` config key are in no way related. That config key is for the `app.php` file. If you want to retrieve a value from the `filesystems.php` file you would need the call to look like `config('filesystems.something')`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to **[Create custom config file in laravel 5](http://sparklinghub.com/create-custom-config-file-in-laravel-5/)**.

The config files contain a list of `key/value` that you can call everywhere in your project.

And the method you see in your project is just a way of managing/structure your app, using config file to define "key/value" list will give you the ability to change the value of any key ("folder_name" in your example) inside the file, and the value will be changed in all the places you're calling the config entry with this key.

**Example :**

If your config file contains `[ 'folder_name' => 'X' ]` and you're using `config('app.files.user_images.folder_name')` in several controllers, the day you want to change the folder name to `Y` in all those controllers you've just to change it in one place (inside the file `[ 'folder_name' => 'Y' ]`) instead on traversing all the controllers searching for the folder name and replace it.

Answer (score -1):

first of all you should use this command in terminal project directory

```
php artisan storage:link
```

after you should use this line in you

```
$request->file('FileName')->store("Public Folder Path hare")
```

it will work fine

Comment: That's not quite an answer to the question "_what's the purpose of config function and it's parameters_"